# is AWS Elastic Beanstalk good for a single index.html website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a very simple pure html website and I want to host it in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

is this a good idea?

when I try to use Elastic Beanstalk, it asks me about the platform (java, node.js, .net, etc) but I do not know which one to select for a single html website.

If I use Elastic Beanstalk, can I later to add more websites using the same platform?

thanks

Comment: If you are looking for an easy and quick solution to host static sites (maybe just to show them to friends or colleagues) I often use https://surge.sh/ . Surge provides a CLI. Just cd into the directory where the index.html lives and run `surge` on the terminal. It will put the site on a domain like `my-site.surge.sh` (you can choose something individual for "my-site") It's my goto solution to get something static online quickly

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to serve a static index.html (along with other static assets, like images) you can use an AWS S3 bucket.

Elastik Beanstalk is a tool for setting up web applications.

Here is a guide from AWS on how to host a static site from S3

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk is a premade setup and hence it understand only the languages they have specified. For eg., since yours is html site, beanstalk should understand that it should serve index.html as the default page when you visit its URL. So it would not work for you. 
I suggest you use S3 for hosting the static website. AWS provides detailed  [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) on how to host static websites on S3.